# Create a profit loss summary of your Trading log in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, trading, journal

I have a trading log something like this in excel workbook -

```
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|    |     A     |     B     |    C     |  D  |               E               |     F      |   G   |    H    |    I    |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | Date      | Stock/ETF | Price    | Qty | Buy/Sell/Deposit/Withdrawn/RH | Adjustment | Fees  | Total   | Balance |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
|  2 | 9/1/2016  |           |          |     | Deposit                       |            |       | $100.00 | $100.00 |
|  3 | 9/29/2016 | MSTX      | $0.1006  | 900 | Buy                           |            |       | $90.54  | $9.46   |
|  4 | 9/30/2016 | MSTX      | $0.1016  | 900 | Sell                          |            | $0.11 | $91.44  | $100.79 |
|  5 | 9/30/2016 | BVX       | $4.9000  | 20  | Buy                           |            |       | $98.00  | $2.79   |
|  6 | 10/3/2016 | AMRS      | $0.5921  | 4   | Buy                           |            |       | $2.37   | $0.42   |
|  7 | 10/3/2016 | BVX       | $5.3700  | 10  | Sell                          |            | $0.00 | $53.70  | $54.12  |
|  8 | 10/3/2016 | NTNX      | $40.1500 | 1   | Buy                           |            |       | $40.15  | $13.97  |
|  9 | 10/3/2016 | AMRS      | $0.5973  | 21  | Buy                           |            |       | $12.54  | $1.43   |
| 10 | 10/3/2016 | AMRS      | $0.5859  | 2   | Buy                           |            |       | $1.17   | $0.26   |
| 11 | 10/4/2016 | NTNX      | $40.2600 | 1   | Sell                          |            | $0.00 | $40.26  | $40.51  |
| 12 | 10/4/2016 | AMRS      | $0.5828  | 27  | Sell                          |            | $0.00 | $15.74  | $56.25  |
| 13 | 10/4/2016 | AUPH      | $3.4800  | 16  | Buy                           | -$0.08     |       | $55.60  | $0.65   |
| 14 | 10/6/2016 | AUPH      | $5.1500  | 16  | Sell                          |            | $0.00 | $82.40  | $83.04  |
| 15 | 10/6/2016 | BVX       | $5.2500  | 10  | Sell                          |            | $0.00 | $52.50  | $135.54 |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+-------------------------------+------------+-------+---------+---------+
```

Here are formulas -

H3 `=IF(((C3*D3)+F3)<>0,((C3*D3)+F3),"")`

I3 `=IF(E3="Buy",I2-H3,IF(E3="Sell",I2+H3-G3,IF(E3="Deposit",I2+H3,IF(E3="Withdrawn",I2-H3,IF(E3="Robin Hood",I2-G3,"")))))`

G4 `=IF(E4="Sell",(D4*C4*0.0000218)+(D4*0.000119),"")`

*Date, Adjustment, Stock/ETF, Price, Qty, Buy/Sell/Deposit/Withdrawn/RH, Adjustment* columns are all entered manually!

I am trying to achieve something like this in excel, where each row refers to the "Sells" in primary table and calculates profit/loss depending on how many shares sold that day and the price at which they were sold. It should also work for partial sells and wont count for shares which are not sold yet -

```
+---+-----------+--------+-------------+
|   |     A     |   B    |      C      |
+---+-----------+--------+-------------+
| 1 | Date      | Ticker | Profit/Loss |
+---+-----------+--------+-------------+
| 2 | 9/30/2016 | MSTX   | $0.90       |
| 3 | 10/3/2016 | BVX    | $4.70       |
| 4 | 10/4/2016 | NTNX   | $0.11       |
| 5 | 10/4/2016 | AMRS   | -$0.34      |
| 6 | 10/6/2016 | AUPH   | $26.80      |
| 7 | 10/6/2016 | BVX    | $3.50       |
+---+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

I have got the Column A and Column B populated. Now I need the Profit/Loss (PL) column to be calculated as per this powershell code -

```
$AllbuyTickers = @()
$AllsellTickers = @()

$AllsellTickers += $Current_Ticker

do
{
    if (closest similar ticker above current cell = "Buy")
    {
        $AllBuyTickers += $This_Ticker
        $OutstandingShares = Sumof($AllbuyTickers.Qty) - Sumof($AllsellTickers.Qty)
    }
    else
    {
        $AllSellTickers += $This_Ticker
    }

    Find the next similar ticker above
}
until ($OutstandingShares >= 0)

if (OutstandingShares < 0)
{
    do
    {
        if (closest similar ticker above current cell = "Buy")
        {
            AllBuyTickers += This Ticker
            OutstandingShares = Sumof(AllbuyTickers.Qty) - Sumof(AllsellTickers.Qty)
        }
        else
        {
            AllSellTickers += This Ticker
        }

        Find the next similar ticker above
    }
    until (OutstandingShares = 0)
}

$AvgSellPrice = Sumof($AllsellTickers.Total) / Sumof($AllsellTickers.qty)
$AvgBuyPrice = Sumof($AllbuyTickers.Total) / Sumof($AllbuyTickers.qty)
$PL = ($AvgSellPrice - $AvgBuyPrice) * Sumof($AllsellTickers.qty)
```

How do I get this working in excel?

Comment: delete duplicates on the date and ticker and do sumifs back to the profit\loss

Comment: Technically I agree with @Lowpar, but I can't understand in which way you (@shaggy_041086) decided what Ticker to show. In other words, why you show "9/30/2016 | MSTX" and not "9/30/2016 | BVX"?

Comment: @Nicolaesse, great point, depends on how relevant the date is?

Comment: @Lowpar its not that easy, I am doing calculations here

Comment: @shaggy_041086, man, you need to use sumifs, they are much easier it can do all the same as the if statements, just more optimised for accounting, and it can sum columns based on criteria.

Comment: @Nicolaesse let me explain in detail how I got the bottom table.
I am calculating profit/loss from sells. Hence 9/30/2016| MSTX was the first sell and thats why it made it to top of table and not BVX. It is sorted per sale date. The profit/loss is calculated by looking if equal or more no of shares were purchased prior to sell or not, if yes, then calculate per share avg price and use this to subtract the sell price (avg. price x no. of shares) from purchase price (avg. price during buy x no. of shares) where the ticker name matches above. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Lowpar can you please elaborate with examples. Appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for a pivot table.